# Move divs aside when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Currently I have a page where two divs are set at the left/right sides of the page with a fixed position and I want to achieve an effect where each div will move aside as you scroll down, but move back into place if you scroll back up.

What I'm working with is currently -

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.left{
    position: fixed;

    left: 0;
    top: 0;

    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;

    background-color: #111111;
}

.right{
    position: fixed;

    right: 0;
    top: 0;

    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;

    background-color: #111111;
}
```

In the HTML, there are just two divs with the class left/right

IS there a `Javascript plugin` or `library` that I can use to easily achieve this effect?

Comment: Can we have a current code?

Comment: I've updated my original post with the CSS I have.

Comment: What about [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr)?. Check out it's demo [here](https://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/).

Comment: You can use the jQuery [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question right it's easy  enough. You could use this little `jquery`:

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.left').css('left', - scroll / 4);
    $('.right').css('right', - scroll / 4);
});
```

which basically detects the current scroll position as a variable (scroll) and you add that value to your `right`and `left` css values. (I divided the mumber by four so it will decrease the "scroll" value added to the css making  the "animation" slower)

```js
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.left').css('left', - scroll / 4);
    $('.right').css('right', - scroll / 4);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 2000px;
  width: 100%;
  margin:0;
}

.left {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #111111;
}

.right {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #111111;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/6mL3q7v9/1/)**